# Error cannot implicity convert type byte[] to byte

Tags: c#

I have a class named `animal`,  it have `public string name`, `species`, and `public Byte photoAnimal`.

In another form I create animal named Simba,and i want to set the value of Simba but when I want to set the `photoAnimal` I get error. I use `filestream` and `binaryreader` to read the data, then `create byte[] imageData = binary` data from `filestream` and binary reader. I cant set the `Simba.photoAnimal = imageData`, here's some of my code:

```
    animal Simba = new animal();
    string fileName = textBox5.Text;
    byte[] ImageData;
    fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    br = new BinaryReader(fs);                    
    ImageData = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
    br.Close();
    fs.Close();    
    Simba.name = textBox1.Text;
    Simba.species = textBox2.Text;
    Simba.photoAnimal = ImageData; // error
```

Comment: The compiler error tells you what is wrong. What do you expect to happen when you assign `byte[]` to a `byte` variable?

Answer (score 7):

ImageData is a byte[]. So in the animal class, replace

```
public Byte photoAnimal
```

by

```
public Byte[] photoAnimal.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message means it cannot assign your `ImageData` (of type `byte[]`) to `photoAnimal`, which seems to be of type `byte`

In your class `animal`, change the type of `photoAnimal` to an array :

```
public class animal
{
    public byte[] photoAnimal;
}
```

As a side note, you inverted the naming convention. variables should be in camelCase and classes in UpperCamelCase. Instead of `animal Simba = new animal(),` in C# you normally use `Animal simba = new Animal()`

Comment: +1, because not only does this work, it mentions the naming conventions that will avoid pain for fellow C# devs.